# Height of QQuickWidget

Tags: qt, qml

I have QWidget. It has vertical layout. Inside: QQuickWidget (call it *quickWidget*
) and QWidget (call it *inputWidget*).

QQuickWidget has ListView inside.

When I change *inputWidget* height by `setMinimumHeight(...); setMaximumHeight(...);`, then the QML quickWidget object covered by this *inputWidget*. And last QML ListView item covered by *inputWidget*. [Picture for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jgNb.png)

I tried to use ListView.positionViewAtEnd() when *inputWidget* change his height. But there is any opportunity dont move elements inside Qml ListView after change height of *inputWidget*?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] instead of explaining your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.